# How can I reverse the list outcome while printing during a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, reverse

I'm trying to print `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`

I only know how to make it print `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

```py
values = []

for numbers in range(0, 6):
    values.append(numbers)

print(values)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `range` function works like this:

```py
range(start, stop, step)
```

Where `start` is the starting point, `stop` is 1 past the stopping point, and step is how the value is updated through each iteration.

```py
values = []

for numbers in range(0, 6):
    values.append(numbers)

for numbers in range(5, -1, -1):
    values.append(numbers)

print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

l = l + l[::-1]

print l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
count = 6
left = []
right = []

for numbers in range(count):
    left.append(numbers)
    right.append(count-numbers-1)

left.extend(right)
print(left)
```